# Dynamic 2D Array in C++, need to multiply even numbers in every row and in whole array

Tags: c++, dynamic

Did second part of the task - multiply all even numbers in 2d dynamic array.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < rows[i]; j++)        
                 if (arr[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                     even *= arr[i][j]; 
                 }
        }
```

and then printed it out.

Tried this with no luck. (Illegal use of pointers):

```
for (j = 0; j < rows[i]; j++) {
                if (arr[j] % 2 == 0) {
                    even *= rows[i];    
                }
}
```

How I should multiply every even number in every row?

Comment: What's `even`? What's `rows`? And what error (exactly) are you getting?

Comment: I am getting - Illegal Use Of Pointer. Ok, forget about dynamic array. How it is done in static 2D arrays? For example, if I have an array of 3 cols and 3 rows.

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION. :D                                                                                      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < rindas[i]; j++)
      if (Masivs[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
       

      even = even * Masivs[i][j]; 
      }
      printf("%hi ", even);
    printf("\n");
    even = 1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the posible solution.

```
    // specify our input array
    int array[4][4] = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    // declare our multiplication result 1 (for multiplication)
    int rows[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    // go though our matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (array[i][j] % 2 == 0) // if the even multiply with specified row result
                rows[i] *= array[i][j];

    // Display the results of multiplications
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << rows[i] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are declaring 2D array with diferent sizes of each row?

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{   
  even = 1;
  for (j = 0; j < rows[i]; j++) {
     even *= arr[i][j];
     println("Row %d: %d\n", i, even);
  }
}
```

arr[j] is a pointer pointing to first element of i-th row. Not a value

Comment: Shouldn't you init even = 1?
(Because otherwise it will stay 0.)

Comment: Yes it's not addition. Thanks :D